# Aligning rows in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

This may sound a newbie question, however I'm new to iOS dev.

I've got a UITableView on my iPad app. TableView has obly three rows, is there a way to tell UITableView to view rows vertically centered, i.e. to not from the top to down.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the sum of the heights of all 3 rows, call it MyTotalHeight.

```
 float MyTotalHeight = heightOfRow0 + heightOfRow1 + heightOfRow2;
```

Set your

```
 tableView.frame = CGRectMake(start_X, start_Y, tableWidth, MyTotalHeight);
```

If you want the contents of each row/cell to be centered vertically within the cell, this will depend greatly on what is in the cell.  You will need to calculate the height of the content and then center that content vertically within the cell by adjusting it's frame.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the UiTableView.sectionHeaderHeight property.  Play with the number until the cells are centered vertically.  If your using a plain table view, I don't know how well this will work for you.

--John